# Find all the group morphisms from $C_3$ to $C_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that since the gcd of 3 and 4 is 1, there can only be one group morphism but I'm unsure of how to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For any two groups $G$ and $H$ there is always a homomorphism $G \to H$.

Answer (score 2):

Between any two groups there is always the trivial homomorphism which sends all elements to the identity of the range group. If there is only one homomorphism between two given groups then it has to be the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $\phi:C_{3}\to C_{4}$ is a group homomorphism, what will be the kernel and image of $\phi$? Especially, what is an order of $\ker(\phi)$? And also an order of $\mathrm{img}(\phi)$? Think about the Lagrange's theorem and the 1st isomorphism theorem.